# knockout 'if' inside an element

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of items and every item has a type. I need to show all the items but every type has its own "configuration" (binding, class, etc.). My code looks like that:

```
        <!-- ko foreach: items -->
                <!-- ko if: itemType == 'type1' -->
                    <div data-bind="value: $parent[itemName]"></div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: itemType == 'type2' -->
                    <div data-bind="value: $parent[itemName], bindingFunc1: foo"></div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: itemType == 'type3' -->
                    <div data-bind="value: $parent[itemName], bindingFunc2: bar"></div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: itemType == 'type4' -->
                    <div data-bind="value: $parent[itemName], bindingFunc1: foo, bindingFunc2: bar"></div>
                <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
```

You can see that **all** of the items has `value: $parent[itemName]` and I just duplicated it.

In my original code - the duplicated code is much much longer and every time I want to change something I need to change it in  all the types.

Is there any way to combine all the lines to one line and insert an "`if (type == ...)`" inside the `div` to add more bindings according the type?

Comment: have a look at [knockout-switch-case](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case)

Comment: Simple add the 'if' quotes to work in IE8

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) that determines the effective element bindings dynamically and applies them to your elements:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myItem = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor(),
            // common bindings here
            effectiveBindings = {
                value: bindingContext.$parent.itemName
            };

        // additional bindings determined by itemType
        switch (value.itemType) {
            case 'type1':
                // nothing
                break;
            case 'type2':
                effectiveBindings.bindingFunc1 = "foo";
                break;
            case 'type3':
                effectiveBindings.bindingFunc2 = "bar";
                break;
            case 'type4':
                effectiveBindings.bindingFunc1 = "foo";
                effectiveBindings.bindingFunc2 = "bar";
                break;
        }

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, effectiveBindings);
    }
};
```

Now you can boil your view down to

```
<!-- ko foreach: items -->
<div data-bind="myItem: $data"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```